# Import .Json files in a MongoDB collection : Error

Tags: json, mongodb

When i type the following request :

```
mongoimport --db splusdb --collection spluscollection --type json --file callForecastAdsl.json --jsonArray
```

It returns :

```
2017-04-13T12:28:48.604+0000    connected to: localhost
2017-04-13T12:28:48.605+0000    Failed: error reading separator after document #1: bad JSON array format - found no opening bracket '[' in input source
2017-04-13T12:28:48.605+0000    imported 0 documents
```

I search on stack overflow, and I find a link which says I have to remove the --jsonArray option.

I did it, and the return is :

```
2017-04-13T12:32:14.506+0000    connected to: localhost
2017-04-13T12:32:14.506+0000    Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character '0' after array element
2017-04-13T12:32:14.506+0000    imported 0 documents
```

The document Json is :

```
{
    "type" : "ADSL",

    "callForecastPerHourAndPerDay" : [[
    [{"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}],       //00h-01h
    [{"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}],
    [{"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}],
    [{"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}],
    [{"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}],
    [{"expected": 50, "higherExpected": 100, "muchHigherExpected": 150}, {"expected": 50, "higherExpected": 100, "muchHigherExpected": 150}, {"expected": 50, "higherExpected": 100, "muchHigherExpected": 150}, {"expected": 50, "higherExpected": 100, "muchHigherExpected": 150}, {"expected": 50, "higherExpected": 100, "muchHigherExpected": 150}, {"expected": 50, "higherExpected": 100, "muchHigherExpected": 150}, {"expected": 50, "higherExpected": 100, "muchHigherExpected": 150}],         //05h-06h
    [{"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}],
    [{"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}],
    [{"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}],
    [{"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500} ,{"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}],
    [{"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}],     //10h-11h
    [{"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}],
    [{"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}],
    [{"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}],
    [{"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}],
    [{"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}],     //15h-16h
    [{"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}],
    [{"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}],
    [{"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}],
    [{"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500} ,{"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}],     //19h-20h
    [{"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500} ,{"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}],
    [{"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}],
    [{"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}],
    [{"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}]        //23h-00h
  ],
  [
    [{"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}],       //00h-01h
    [{"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}],
    [{"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}],
    [{"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}],
    [{"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}, {"expected": 25, "higherExpected": 50, "muchHigherExpected": 75}],
    [{"expected": 50, "higherExpected": 100, "muchHigherExpected": 150}, {"expected": 50, "higherExpected": 100, "muchHigherExpected": 150}, {"expected": 50, "higherExpected": 100, "muchHigherExpected": 150}, {"expected": 50, "higherExpected": 100, "muchHigherExpected": 150}, {"expected": 50, "higherExpected": 100, "muchHigherExpected": 150}, {"expected": 50, "higherExpected": 100, "muchHigherExpected": 150}, {"expected": 50, "higherExpected": 100, "muchHigherExpected": 150}],         //05h-06h
    [{"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}],
    [{"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}],
    [{"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}],
    [{"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500} ,{"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}],
    [{"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}],     //10h-11h
    [{"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}],
    [{"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}],
    [{"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}],
    [{"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}],
    [{"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}],     //15h-16h
    [{"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}],
    [{"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}],
    [{"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}, {"expected": 2000, "higherExpected": 2500, "muchHigherExpected": 3000}],
    [{"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500} ,{"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}],     //19h-20h
    [{"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500} ,{"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}, {"expected": 1000, "higherExpected": 1800, "muchHigherExpected": 2500}],
    [{"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}, {"expected": 500, "higherExpected": 1000, "muchHigherExpected": 1500}],
    [{"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}, {"expected": 250, "higherExpected": 500, "muchHigherExpected": 750}],
    [{"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}, {"expected": 100, "higherExpected": 200, "muchHigherExpected": 300}]        //23h-00h
  ]
]}
```

Why it doesn't work ? How to explain this comportment ?

Answer (score 0):

this JSON data is too big... try any JSON valid edtior  to find  where is wrong in the document. Error is due to invalid  JSON format so check the document.

Comment: According to my editor (Sublime Text), there is no error in the json file. And i didn't have copied the entire json file here, just a part in order to illustrate that is a 3-dimensionnal array.

Comment: try after removing the  all comment "//".... i am getting  error in it ...

Comment: I have just done it, it's working.

When it was just config file, it did't cause problem, but it Json, yes...

thanks for your answer !

Comment: then try robomongo, connect the robomongo with same local connection, and go to that collection then try this document without any command, in graphical view